# Load path JSON when hit enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I need have to carry the description of the title when clicking "enter", 
I created a variable for the path of the description:

```
var descri = json.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
    return item.summary;

});
```

And this code, jQuery to call the the variable when you click enter:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function (e) {

    if (e.which == 13) {

        //I think the error is here:
        $('.description').html('descri');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NmnB/1/)

Comment: `'descri'` is a literal string, it will just put that word in `.description`, not the contents of the variable. And because you used `.map()`, `descri` contains an array, not a string of HTML. It's not clear what you want to do. Can you show what's in `descri` and explain what you want in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
success: function (json) {

    /* Other things */

    // description
    var description = json.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
        return item.summary;
    });
    // Call Ajax Key Enter
    $(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $('.description').html(description);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    /* Other things */

}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/2NmnB/2/

Comment: exactly, thank you. looking here the text was loaded I saw that the path of this variable also wrong, do you know how to load the description of each item? Thank you.

Comment: @cristianoveloz I'm not sure what do you mean, the path to the descriptions is right. Maybe the problem is that `description` is an array with all descriptions, and `$('.description').html(description)` mixes the all - maybe wrapping each description inside a `<p>` element would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly then here is your answer below.

```
if (e.which == 13) {
    $('.description').html($(".nav_holder li.selected").text());

}
```